# xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection singleton instance not singleton?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, xunit

I'm writing unit tests for different singleton architectures. Had 2 issues as below:
I have a code as below

```
public class SingletonThreadSafeDependencyInjectionTests : TestBed<TestStartup>
...
[Fact]
    public void MultiThreadedInstanceShouldReturnSameInstance()
    {
        SingletonTestHelpers.RunMultiThreadTests(
            () => _fixture.GetService<SingletonThreadSafeDependencyInjection>(_testOutputHelper));
    }
```

and then...

```
public class SingletonTestHelpers
...
//arrange
        var integerCount = new int[3];
        var instances = new List<SingletonBase>();
        var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };

        //act
        Parallel.ForEach(integerCount, options, instance =>
        {
            instances.Add(singletonBase.Invoke());
        });

        //assert
        instances[0].Id.ShouldBe(instances[1].Id);
        instances[2].Id.ShouldBe(instances[1].Id);
        instances[0].Id.ShouldBe(instances[2].Id);
```

Problem 1) I expect parallel for each to run three times, sometimes it runs only once - array index out of range exception is thrown.

Problem 2) Sometimes I get three different instances, while one could expect to have one.

See: https://github.com/memoz1981/design_patterns

Comment: I find your question confusing. What are you trying to test here? Are you testing whether the DI Container always contains a single instance? If so, stop doing this. Take a look at the documentation of the DI Container to see the guarantees it makes. Besides multi-threading, and especially the absence of race conditions are really hard to test deterministicly. Or are you testing the implementation of your Singleton pattern? (the Singleton pattern is the opposite of DI and the Singleton *lifestyle* has little to do with the Singleton pattern). And what are "singleton architectures"?

Comment: hi Steven - thanks for your response. Just trying to think about Singleton lifetime vs Singleton pattern - you mean this is just name coincidence? I just had a course in Pluralsight from quite a senior guy, who said the opposite - so I'm confused. I'm trying to test different design patterns - so here I'm trying to implement singleton with different architectures - using static constructor, static instance, lazy, dependency injection etc. and trying to resolve them and see if I get same or different instances each time I ask it. pattern using DI container seems to return different instance.

Comment: The Singleton pattern and the DI Singleton lifestyle share that they guarantee the existence of only one instance (in a given context), but this is where the similarity ends. The Singleton pattern always leads to *tight coupling* between the consumer and its Singleton dependency, while DI proposes *lose coupling* and there is no tight coupling with the Singleton lifestyle. I have no idea which Pluralsight video you are refering to, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: In [my book on DI](https://mng.bz/BYNl), I spent about 8 pages describing why this is a bad idea. It's chapter 5 "Anti-Patterns", section 5.3, page 146, but a free summary can be found [here](https://mng.bz/8JqB). Although that discussion centers around the Ambient Context rather than the Singleton pattern, the argumentation against using the Singleton design pattern is identical to Ambient Context, so you can replace the wording "Ambient Context" with "Singleton design pattern" to understand the problems with the Singleton design pattern.

Comment: This doesn't make the Singleton design pattern always a bad pattern, but it is simply unsuited to be used in the situation where you wish to be able to replace the dependency, as with the Singleton design pattern the implementation is fixed at compile time; it can't be replaced. If the ability to replace the dependency at runtime is a requirement (for instance for testing), in that case DI is a much better fit and constructor injection should preferably be used.

Comment: thanks very much for detailed answers - didn't know you had a book - will definitely read it.